# Using Scala libraries in Processing

Tags: scala, processing

I'm not much of a java programmer. I really like Scala a lot more than java. If I could I'd could I'd rather make processing libraries in Scala to use in Processing. I've been able to initiate new objects from my library in Processing, but I can't yet figure out how to reach methods or fields from my Scala object. I also can't seem to pass the current PApplet into the Scala object without an error. How I did it was by copying scala-library.jar into the lib folder of Processing so it can use scalaObjects.

If I do:

```
new Foo();
//or
Foo bar = new Foo();
```

There's no problem.

But if I do:

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
println(bar.baz);
```

It says baz doesn't exist, baz is just a string.

If I do:

```
new Foo(this);
```

It says Foo(library) doesn't exist.

**I'm obviously missing something, is there someone much more knowledgeable than me out there who can give me a hint?**

[update]
Also, I noticed that when I do this in processing:

```
println(new Foo());
```

The console prints out, library.Foo@aa233f

Comment: can you show what class Foo looks like?

Comment: Is `library` a package or an object?

Answer (score 1):

These are typical Java/Scala interop issues. You should give the definition code of Foo to get specific help, but you can find lots of existing help/info by searching for scala interop.

Have you had a look at SPDE? It's an offshot of Processing which supports Scala. If it's mature enough, you may be better off using it rather than dealing with all these interop issues.